# \sbox in math mode

Tags: math-mode, boxes

I want to extract the width of an equation, but it gives me an error.

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
```

I do not understand what is missing.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand{\insertTableMybox}{}
\renewcommand{\insertTableMybox}{%
    \begin{equation*}
        W =
        \begin{bmatrix}
            0                 & w_{1,2} & \ldots & w_{1,U} \\
            w_{2,1}           & 0       & \ldots & w_{2,U} \\
            \vdots            & \vdots  & \ddots & \vdots  \\
            w_{U,1} & w_{U,2} & \ldots  & 0                \\
        \end{bmatrix},
        \text{ where } W \in [0,1]^{U\times U}.
    \end{equation*}
}

\begin{document}
    \insertTableMybox
    %\sbox0{\insertTableMybox} % <- not working
    \fbox{\begin{minipage}{\wd0}
        bla 
    \end{minipage}}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,varwidth}
\newsavebox\myBox
\newcommand\insertTableMybox{%
  \varwidth{\linewidth}
    \[
    W =
    \begin{bmatrix}
    0                 & w_{1,2} & \ldots & w_{1,U} \\
    w_{2,1}           & 0       & \ldots & w_{2,U} \\
    \vdots            & \vdots  & \ddots & \vdots  \\
    w_{U,1} & w_{U,2} & \ldots  & 0                \\
    \end{bmatrix},
    \text{ where } W \in [0,1]^{U\times U}.
    \]
\endvarwidth
}

\begin{document}
    \insertTableMybox

    \fbox{\insertTableMybox}

    \sbox\myBox{\insertTableMybox}  \the\wd\myBox

\end{document}
```

Comment: I was actually writing the same with `varwidth` package. But you were faster than me. Thanks to David that pointed the use of `minipage`.

Answer (score 4):

An `\sbox` is like `\mbox` and its content is in horizontal (LR) mode so can not have display material like an equation. You could put a `minipage` containing the equation in the box, but its width is then the width that you specify for the minipage.

To box a display see the `\boxed` command in `amsmath`.

Comment: It would be useful to have the definition of `\boxed`. I just want to extract the width to use in another application (not shown in the MWE).

Comment: @cacamailg a displayed equation, like a paragraph doesn't really have a natural width. it is always set to the specified width. In this simple case you could set the equation just in inline math `\sbox0{$w=...`  without the equation number, but not clear if that is enough for your use case in general.

Answer (score 3):

If all you want is to measure the width of the equation, use inline math mode, with `\displaystyle`; there's no need to start display math mode.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand{\insertTableMybox}{}
\renewcommand{\insertTableMybox}{%
  W =
  \begin{bmatrix}
  0                 & w_{1,2} & \ldots & w_{1,U} \\
  w_{2,1}           & 0       & \ldots & w_{2,U} \\
  \vdots            & \vdots  & \ddots & \vdots  \\
  w_{U,1} & w_{U,2} & \ldots  & 0                \\
  \end{bmatrix},
  \text{ where } W \in [0,1]^{U\times U}.
}

\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
\insertTableMybox
\\
\sbox0{$\displaystyle\insertTableMybox$}%
\fbox{%
  \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\wd0-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}
  bla 
  \end{minipage}%
}
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

[image]